# How to use pygame.surface.scroll()?

Tags: python, pygame

I just found out about `pygame.surface.scroll()` and what I understand from the pygame documents that `scroll()` is for moving surface without the need to rebuild the background again to cover the old surface, just like `pygame.rect.move_ip()` but for surfaces.

Anyway, I don't know how to use it and the examples in the pygame documents are hard to me to understand as long as I am beginner and, after searching for long time, I couldn't found anything useful to understand how to use it.

Here is my code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1250,720))
pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
boxx=200
boxy=200
image = pygame.Surface([20,20]).convert_alpha()
image.fill((255,255,255))
while True :
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT :
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    image.scroll(10,10)
    screen.blit(image,(boxx,boxy))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Your `image` and `screen` variables are backwards. That is also causing you some confusion I'm sure..

Your problem may is that you are trying to scroll an all black background. It is probably scrolling, and you just don't know it because the white box you used `blit()` to draw on the screen is stationary.

Try using something you can see scroll, like an image file. If you wanna move the white box, you can add a counter as a speed variable. Read this, then run it.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1250,720))
pygame.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
boxx=200
boxy=200
image = pygame.Surface([20,20]).convert_alpha()
image.fill((255,255,255))
speed = 5   # larger values will move objects faster
while True :
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT :
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    image.scroll(10,10)
    # I did modulus 720, the surface width, so it doesn't go off screen
    screen.blit(image,((boxx + speed) % 720, (boxy + speed) % 720))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I can't say for sure the scroll function is working or not, learn to use an image as your background so you can see it moving first.

Comment: thank you lot yes this was my mistake for making black background  and i was supposed to make screen.scroll() not image.scroll()

Comment: @مهندعبدالجليل You should accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: Are you missing a `speed += 1` (or some #) at the end?